# Date conditions using Search logic

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, datetime, timezone, searchlogic

The Rails plugin - [Searchlogic](http://github.com/binarylogic/searchlogic), from binary logic - offers the ability to filter by date.  I have my form set up like so...

```
<% form_for @search do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :start %> <%= f.select :due_at_after, [[['','']],['November', '2009-11-01'.to_date],['December', '2009-12-01'.to_date]]  %><br>
    <%= f.label :end %> <%= f.select :due_at_before, [[['','']],['December', '2009-12-01'.to_date],['January', '2010-01-01'.to_date]]  %>
    <%= f.submit 'Search' %>
<% end %>
```

But, the date I'm getting back from the @search object as generated in the controller...

```
@search = Task.with_member(current_user).search(params[:search])
```

is generating a date param that looks like this

```
{:due_at_after=>Sat, 31 Oct 2009 20:00:00 EDT -04:00}
```

With the two formats, the form will not show the drop-down as selected.  It looks as if the format in the searchlogic object uses a timezone adjusted time, too.

Any thoughts on how to handle this?

Comment: I found that the calendar_date_select gem works, yet still with some problems.  The date format changes, but in the text field, that's less of a problem than with a select box.  Still looking for the right way to do this.

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280980/searchlogic-doesnt-convert-the-time-properly-for-datetime-conditions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A big part of your issue seems to be happening because you are converting strings into dates, and dates back to strings. I believe you might be doing it more than you need to.

HTML forms don't really "understand" dates - they just "understand" strings. So it is ok to pass them strings instead dates. In other words, it is ok to remove the `to_date`.

```
<% form_for @search do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :start %>
    <%= f.select :due_at_after,
          ['November', '2009-11-01'],['December', '2009-12-01']],
          :include_blank => true
    %>
    <br/>
    <%= f.label :end %>
    <%= f.select :due_at_before,
          [['December', '2009-12-01'],['January', '2010-01-01']],
          :include_blank => true
    %>
    <%= f.submit 'Search' %>
<% end %>
```

Also, I prefer using `:include_blank => true` instead of `[['','']]` (more human-readable, in my opinion), and I used a closed `<br/>` tag (standard html stuff - maybe you made a typo?).

By the way, if you want to specify a Date, you can use a Date constructor. It is shorter to write and faster to execute than creating a string and parsing a date from it.

```
#Date(2009,11,1) is faster, shorter, and equivalent
Date(2009,11,1) == '2009-11-01'.to_date # --> true
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to find records for a given month? Check out my [by_star](http://github.com/radar/by_star) gem/plugin for this.