# How can I count and filter on an associated record in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

Company has_many Contacts

Company has_many ContactEmails :through => :contacts

ContactEmail belongs_to Contact

Contact belongs_to Company

Contact has_many ContactEmails

For a specific instance of Company, how can I find all ContactEmails and filter on an attribute, such as date_sent?

I tried Company.ContactEmails but I don't think it can make that association.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use a named scope for this. This works for Rails 2.3, but wouldn't change much for Rails 3.

I haven't tested it, but something like this should work. The conditions may need to be tweaked for a proper date comparison.

```
ContactEmail < ActiveRecord::Base
  named_scope :by_date_sent, lambda {|d| { :conditions => ["date_sent = ?", d]}}
end

@company.contact_emails.by_date_sent(Date.today)
```

Comment: interesting...I don't know a has_one :through for Contactemails?

Comment: hmmm...you are right....I didn't use a lambda for named scope just use conditions....should I use it?  wondering why searchlogic isn't allowing me to do the same thing....are you familiar with searchlogic?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with searchlogic, other than just reading the github README. It seems like it could work, but I didn't see any examples that dealt with dates. I did come across someone using it for this purpose though http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1829477/date-conditions-using-search-logic

Answer (score 0):

At least 2 semantic of ways to do it:

1. Through `named_scope` as Beerlington has suggested (The right way to do it).
2. Just pass the conditions to the finders:
   `company.contact_emails.all(:conditions => ["date_sent = ?", d])`